# Kafka Consumer not fetching all messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I am trying to launch dynamic consumer whenever new topic is created in Kafka but dynamically launched consumer is missing starting/first message always but consuming the message from there on. I am using kafka-python module and am using updated KafkaConsumer and KafkaProducer.

Code for Producer is

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
record_metadata = producer.send(topic, data)
```

and code for consumer is

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,group_id="abc",bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',auto_offset_reset='earliest')
```

Please suggest something to over come this problem or any configuration i have to include in my producer and consumer instances.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic consumer?

Comment: i am launching consumer whenever new topic is created. Am calling these consumers as dynamic as they are launched on run time.

Comment: In your consumer, you are giving topic. How do you know the topic name?  Is consumer stream created after data is published? Do check my answer... I think thats the likely solution

Comment: Yes i tried offset value as well but it is not fetching the first message that has been published. Messages published then after are getting fetched. Newly created topic names are fetched from zookeeper.

Comment: can you paste your updated KafaConsumer code?

Comment: Its working now with earliest option and auto_commit to true. Thanks leo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set auto_offset_reset to earliest.

When a new consumer stream is created, it starts from latest offset (which is default value for auto_offset_reset) and you will miss messages which were sent while consumer wasn't started.

You can read about it in [kafka python doc](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html). Relevant portion is below

> auto_offset_reset (str) – A policy for resetting offsets on
> OffsetOutOfRange errors: ‘earliest’ will move to the oldest available
> message, ‘latest’ will move to the most recent. Any ofther value will
> raise the exception. Default: ‘latest’.